# Speak misses words when executed first time in new cell

Tags: core-language, sound

Version->12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)
ReleaseID->12.1.1.0 (6959458, 2020061902)
PatchLevel->0

When I evaluate for the first time in a new input cell:

```
Speak["1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10"]
```

I only hear 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 or sometime 6 7 8 9 10 only
Re-evaluating the same cell again results in hearing the complete sentence.
After waiting a while or when programming a bit further and going back to the input cell with speak the same happens again.  The first time there are words missing and the next time it's fine again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the headset I'm using. (Jabra with Radiolink 370 https://www.jabra.nl/accessories/jabra-link-370#/#14208-08).
when using the laptop speaker everything is fine.
Using Bluetooth or USB cable also works fine